# view the GUI of a .net application on remote pc (no remote desktop or vnc etc.)

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, user-interface, remoting

I read several articles but didn't get an understanding regarding WCF (or remoting or ...).

I have written a .NET 4.0 WinForms application running on one PC where a user is making inputs.

I would like to display the GUI of the application on a second PC.
No inputs on the second PC, just viewing the application.

How might this be possible? (WCF or no WCF?)
(controlling the whole PC with remote desktop or vnc is no option)

Thanks a lot for any suggestions,
Ralf

Comment: You're looking for a desktop sharing application (Some of them can be configured to share just one application, rather than your whole desktop).

Comment: You could take screenshots of the application and send it to the other PC through WCF maybe? That's the easiest (at the same time ugliest) solution I can think of.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange That's a pretty naive implementation of screen sharing, and it doesn't really scale well.  You end up sending a *lot* of redundant data and as such generally can't get good frame rates.  There are much more sophisticated algorithms that basically send incremental changes, but at the end of the day you should probably just use an existing product for this rather than rolling your own.

Comment: @Servy That is why I said it's probably the ugliest solution. But if he really wants to write his own app instead of using another tool or api, that would be an starting point.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: Even if ugly, how would this be done, sending the GUI of the application as an image per WCF?

Comment: @Servy: Do you know of such a third party library or product sharing only an application?

Comment: @IronKalli Nope, I'm just telling you what to look for.  I know there are a number of them out there; I doubt they're hard to find at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the main application expose a WCF service and have a second view application consume the service to view the data.

Comment: If I understood it right I could use WCF to receive remote objects and I can build a client which parses the objects and might show their data.
Does WCF provide a feature to show the GUI of my application in a browser (IE?) without writing my own client?

Comment: No. If you want a read only experience on another system, you will have to create a read-only client.

Answer (score 0):

If viewing the area of the screen the application resides in is an option, my library [RemoteViewing](http://www.zer7.com/software/remoteviewing) may be sufficient for you.

The included example server (it includes both client and server VNC) is read-only.

In the example server, instead of passing a Screen as a second argument to VncScreenFramebufferSource's constructor (that will capture the entire screen), provide a callback to the screen rectangle containing the application. That should be all you need.